# Adding a highlight animation when hovering a sortable object over a droppable object JQUERY

Tags: jquery, droppable, jquery-ui-sortable, addclass

I have a list of objects called projects that are sortable, and a list of objects called categories that are droppable. I need to somehow make it so that when you click on a sortable project, and drag it down so it is hovering over a droppable category, the category that the project is going to go into is highlighted, or outlined or some other kind of animation.

I am sure that it could be done by something as simple as an add-class-on-hover-over-droppable-object type function, but I don't know how it is supposed to be setup.

Looking through some of the jQuery documentation, I found out that for a droppable object, you can set an `over: function(),` attribute, but I couldn't get it to work...

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `hoverClass` option. [One of the demos for jQuery droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#accepted-elements) uses it (click on `view source` to view how it works).

```
$("#something").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'someClassName'
});
```